# For loop for converting columns into numerical

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am an beginner and trying to get into R.
I have a dataset with 37 columns of which I want to transform columns 2 to 37 into numerical.
This expression works perfectly for conversion of a column seperately:

```
Factor2 <- as.numeric(as.character(Factor2))
```

I came up with the following loop but it does not convert the columns:

```
for(i in 2:37) {
  colnames(dataset)[i] <- as.numeric(as.character(colnames(dataset)[i])) 
}
```

Comment: No, columns are still not numerical

Comment: If you want to change the columns then why are operating on the column names? Changing Tim's name to Chef doesn't make him a chef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to change the column names, you want to change the columns. So you need to subset it using `dataset[row-index, col-index]`. e.g. if you want to select all rows of the second column of your dataset, use `dataset[, i]`.

You can the use `<<-` to change the dataset in the parent environment of your loop. Also, I use `sapply()` which is more efficient than a for loop:

```
sapply(2:37, function(i) {
  dataset[, i] <<- as.numeric(as.character(dataset[, i]))
})
```

Reproducible example using `mtcars` as `dataset`:

```
dataset <- mtcars

str(dataset)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...



sapply(2:ncol(dataset), function(i) {
  dataset[, i] <<- as.character(dataset[, i])
})

str(dataset)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : chr  "6" "6" "4" "6" ...
 $ disp: chr  "160" "160" "108" "258" ...
 $ hp  : chr  "110" "110" "93" "110" ...
 $ drat: chr  "3.9" "3.9" "3.85" "3.08" ...
 $ wt  : chr  "2.62" "2.875" "2.32" "3.215" ...
 $ qsec: chr  "16.46" "17.02" "18.61" "19.44" ...
 $ vs  : chr  "0" "0" "1" "1" ...
 $ am  : chr  "1" "1" "1" "0" ...
 $ gear: chr  "4" "4" "4" "3" ...
 $ carb: chr  "4" "4" "1" "1" ...
```

Comment: does not work either. is.numeric(Factor2) still returns False

Comment: is.numeric still returns false for any given variable after running your code. When I convert the columns seperately via theexample in my original post the variables are being converted into numerical and is.numeric returns true.

Comment: what's the output of `sapply(dataset, is.numeric)` (with the proposed solution)?

Comment: TRUE for all converted variables. I think your solution worked, thank you. But do you have an idea why is.numeric(FactorB) still returns FALSE even though it is apparently a numerical variable now!?

Comment: If you want to check the column `FactorB` from the `data.frame` `dataset`, you would use `dataset$FactorB`. otherwise you only check the object `FactorB` in your environment.

Comment: Oh, I see...thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: no worries. if you want, you can accept the answer if it solves your problem.